# How to set the maximum TCP receive window size in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, tcp

I already tried to set the following registry keys:

- GlobalMaxTcpWindowSize to 2KB ([MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957546.aspx))
- TcpWindowSize for each interface to 2KB ([MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938219.aspx))

Unfortunately, I seems that these registry keys have no effect (also after a reboot).
I tried testing using iperf which prints the default TCP window size on startup. In my case it printed 8KB before these modifications and 8KB afterwards...

Any hints, ideas are welcome!
Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: There is nothing 'maximum' about those sizes.  *As you have already shown,* they are in fact one quarter of the default sizes, which historically had been miles too low for decades. A large TCP window is 48k or more. 2k is completely useless. You'd be better off leaving it strictly alone.

Comment: The value 2KB was choosen just as an example value to check if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all auto on vista+ please see

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/87969-heres-why-tcpwindowsize-does-not-work-in-vista/

Comment: Thanks for the link, very informative. So, there is no more option how to set the default/maximum value for the TCP receive window size? Also if I disable the autoscaling mechanism?